# Reducing resolution of huge categorical raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, resolution

I'm not much of a GIS user, but I've got a big ascii file that I'm trying to convert into a

```
lat  long  data
x1   y1     d1
x1   y2     d2
x1   y3     d3
x2   y1     d4
...
etc
```

format, so that I can work with it in R.  I've got global national identifier data (i.e.: which country occupies what grid) at 2.5 arc-minute resolution, but I want to coarsen it into half-degree, because that is the resolution of the rest of my data.  I could do so in R if the file weren't so large -- its 3.9GB and I can't read it into memory.  A NetCDF file would obviously be ideal for me, but I can't find a netcdf version of the data I want.

The data is categorical -- country identifiers.  What I want to do is simple to take each 12x12 block of gridcells, evaluate that N=144 matrix, and return the country that appears the most times.  (I'd also like it to ignore NA values, unless all values are NA).  This would be easy enough in R if I could only open the darn text file.

So I opened QGIS, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to "coarsen" a raster.

Is there one?

Then it occured to me that I could convert the data to vector, and then convert it *back* to raster, specifying the resolution that I want.

BUT is there a way to do so that would allow me to specify that each gridcell should be .5x.5 degrees, going from -180 to 180 and -90 to 90?

This seems like a pretty gross hack.

Is there a better way?

---

I've decided that it makes more sense for me to just make the file into a netcdf using a remote machine with the memory for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Translate (under Raster-->Conversion) using the Outsize option.
[image]

In the example picture, the setting 25% will produce pixels that are 4x larger.  So, to convert your 2.5 minute raster to 30' (0.5°), you would use 8%.  I'm not sure what the limitations are, if any, for lat/long pixels, but it should work.

Comment: Which resampling method does this use?

Comment: I have this question too, but the latest GQIS doesn't have an Outsize parameter in Translate.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything I advice you to read this Question: [Exporting DEM-derived rasters to CSV from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/exporting-dem-derived-rasters-to-csv-from-qgis)

The workflow I would take would be something like this:

1. Create a vrt of the raster with the desired resolution:
   [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) -of VRT -tr  output.vrt
   [gdalfile].
2. Use gdal2xyz.py (usually it is located to C:/OSGeo4W/bin) to create a xyz file from raster.