# Exporting slope values from DEM-derived rasters to CSV from QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, export, vector-grid, slope

I want to export the slope values with their corresponding latitude and longitude into a CSV file. There's a DEM of a region having an irregular shape (not square). I have to generate the slope rate map of the region using DEM then create grid points at 50m intervals and get the corresponding values of the slope at all the grid points with their latitudes and longitudes in a CSV format.

I had the slope raster map now but don't know how to proceed forward getting slope values in CSV format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting DEM-derived rasters to CSV from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/exporting-dem-derived-rasters-to-csv-from-qgis)

Comment: Actually, I referred to it too but the thing is I only want to export slope values from certain grid points, not from the whole raster

Comment: PyQGIS script would be an option for you?